# iOS - NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest method not getting a response in offline mode

Tags: ios, image, asynchronous

Hey I'm new to iPhone and I have been trying to display image icons on table view cell in offline mode.

Using `NSUserDefault` i am storing array objects locally in Online mode. I am using a method that creates a `NSURLRequest`, and sends that request with the `NSURLConnection` method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler`:. Sometimes I am not getting any response using this method, so completionHandler is not calling. So i am not getting any image icon on table. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**here is my code :**

```
QuickLinksTab *quickLinksmenu = [[QuickLinksTab alloc] init];
quickLinksmenu = [arrayLinks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblName.text = quickLinksmenu.title;

NSString *strQuickLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",quickLinksmenu.iconImage];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:strQuickLink];

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                                           NSData * data,
                                           NSError * error) {
                           if (error)
                           {
                               NSLog(@"ERROR CONNECTING DATA FROM SERVER: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                           }
                           else{
                               UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
                               // do whatever you want with image
                               if (image) {
                                   cell.imageIcon.image = image;
                               }
                               else{
                                   cell.imageIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultPlace.png"];
                               }

                           }
                       }];
```

QuickLinksTab is my entity class, i am storing `quickLinksmenu.title` and `quickLinksmenu.iconImage` locally in my app. I am getting Error message - `

> ERROR CONNECTING DATA FROM SERVER:
>
> The Internet connection appears to be offline.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: set the DefaultPlace.png where you catch the error as well

Comment: @CalinChituYes i can set DefaultPlace.png image, but every time if user device has no internet then it will never display any server image.

Comment: in that case you have to think about some caching method, I used this in the past https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage